# Error using for loop [procedural assignment to a non-register i is not permitted]

Tags: verilog

I'm not really experienced with Verilog. I'm trying to make an RCA using a for loop but I'm getting an error when trying to synthesize the modules.

The error I'm getting is

> procedural assignment to a non-register i is not permitted

```
//1-bit full adder
module fadder (s, cout, a, b, cin);
input   a, b, cin;
output  s, cout;

assign s = (a ^ b) ^ cin;
assign cout = ((a & b) | ((a | b) & cin));
endmodule

//RCA Logic
module part1(s, cout, a, b, cin, clk);
parameter BIT_WIDTH = 128;

input [BIT_WIDTH-1:0] a, b;
input cin;
input clk;
output cout;
output [BIT_WIDTH-1:0] s;

wire [BIT_WIDTH:0] cin_wire;

assign cin_wire[0] = cin;   

genvar i;   

generate
always@(posedge clk) 
begin
    for(i = 0; i <= BIT_WIDTH-1; i = i + 1) //error is on this line
    begin:
        fadder fadder_inst (.s(s[i]), .cout(cin_wire[i+1]), .a(a[i]), .b(b[i]), .cin(cin_wire[i]));
    end
end

endgenerate

assign cout = cin_wire[BIT_WIDTH];

endmodule
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
generate 
for(i = 0; i <= BIT_WIDTH-1; i = i + 1)
begin
  fadder fadder_inst (.s(s[i]), .cout(cin_wire[i+1]), .a(a[i]), .b(b[i]), .cin(cin_wire[i]));
end
endgenerate
```

You can not generate the modules inside always block.

You have to seperately manipulate input inside always block before connecting to fadder_inst.

What I guess is, RCA is not clock dependent. Its purly asynchronous circuit.

Comment: What about the clk signal? What do you mean by separately manipulate input inside always block? Please help.

Comment: So RCA is clock dependent circuit?

Comment: Yes, it is clock dependent. It is instantiated with a clock from a top circuit.

Comment: Can you upload actual circuit diagram which having clock for RCA!!?

Comment: I don't have the actual circuit diagram, sorry. I think the RCA shouldn't be clock dependent since it's purely combinational. You have any thoughts?

Comment: http://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/ripple-carry-adder.png look at this link.

Comment: @ElDj you can not instantiate inside a `always @(posedge clock` block. Only register assignments should be done inside the clock block. Instances describe physical hardware not triggered software functions.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot instantiate a module inside a procedural block (initial,
>   always, always_comb, always_ff, always_latch, final, task, function).

You can do like following to serve your purpose.

```
module fadder (clk, s, cout, a, b, cin);
  input   a, b, cin, clk;
  output reg  s, cout;

  always @ (posedge clk)
  begin
    s = (a ^ b) ^ cin;
    cout = ((a & b) | ((a | b) & cin));
  end
endmodule

//RCA Logic
module part1(s, cout, a, b, cin, clk);
  parameter BIT_WIDTH = 128;

  input [BIT_WIDTH-1:0] a, b;
  input cin;
  input clk;
  output cout;
  output [BIT_WIDTH-1:0] s;

  wire [BIT_WIDTH:0] cin_wire;

  assign cin_wire[0] = cin;   

  genvar i;   
  generate
  begin
    for(i = 0; i <= BIT_WIDTH-1; i = i + 1) //error is on this line
    begin:
      fadder fadder_inst (.clk(clk), .s(s[i]), .cout(cin_wire[i+1]), .a(a[i]), .b(b[i]), .cin(cin_wire[i]));
    end
  end  
  endgenerate

  assign cout = cin_wire[BIT_WIDTH];
endmodule
```

Comment: Sequential logic should be assigned with non-blocking assignments (`<=`). In this solution it will take 4 clock cycles to calculate the results, which I doubt is desired.

Comment: Yes ideally sequential logic should use `<=`. But in this case it wont change anything, because none of the registers are used as inputs in any other expression. And I don't understand about 4 clock cycle? I think it will give results in every cycle.

Comment: It is actually worse than 4 cycles, it is up to `BIT_WIDTH` cycles (not sure where I got the 4 from, maybe read the code to quickly and thought BIT_WIDTH had a value of 4). `cout` is being flopped at each fulladder, therefore it will take a clock cycle to propagate each stage. Example if a=15, b=1, cin=0, it would take 4 clocks to get the output s=16. Try it on a simulator with using using non-blocking assignment (making sure there isn't a race condition in the scheduler) or use a study the gate level schematic generated from synthesize.

Comment: Ok. I think you are talking about the inherent delay of ripple carry adder. Yes it will be there.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you cannot instantiate modules inside an always block. The need to be separated and a new wire needs to be created to connect the two.

In the below example `cout` and `s` are `reg` type outputs. There is an added wire `s_wire` (following your naming convention based `cin_wire`) which is connected to the `s` output of the `fadder_inst` instances. `part1`'s `s` and `cout` output is synchronously assigned to `s_wire` and `cin[BIT_WIDTH]` respectivly. Note that they are assigned with non-blocking assignments (`<=`).

```
// ...
output reg cout;
output reg [BIT_WIDTH-1:0] s;

wire [BIT_WIDTH-1:0] s_wire;
wire [BIT_WIDTH:0] cin_wire;
assign cin_wire[0] = cin;   

genvar i;
generate
  for(i = 0; i <= BIT_WIDTH-1; i = i + 1)
  begin
    fadder fadder_inst (.s(s_wire[i]), .cout(cin_wire[i+1]), .a(a[i]), .b(b[i]), .cin(cin_wire[i]));
  end
endgenerate

always@(posedge clk)
begin
  s <= s_wire;
  cout <= cin_wire[BIT_WIDTH];
end
// ...
```